# Determine which graphics driver Xorg uses

Tags: xorg, drivers, graphics

On a fresh Arch Linux installation, I had difficulties with the graphics drivers. In the process, I have installed a lot of different drivers to somehow get the display working.

Now I need to determine which driver X is using. How to do that?

The installed packages include `xf86-video-intel`, `xf86-video-nouveau`, `nvidia`, `xorg-drivers`. To solve a strange issue to launch any graphical desktop manager i had to replace `nividia-libgl` with `mesa-libgl`.

Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 / Nvidia GT 750M

The content of `Xorg.0.log` is: http://pastebin.com/YwiMZmG6

Comment: `xrandr --listproviders`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the Xorg startup log file, usually `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and look at which modules it is loading.  By default Xorg can try to autodetect but you can manually force a driver by putting a `Device` stanza in an Xorg conf file.  Here is what the Xorg startup log will look like for an nvidia card and the nvidia proprietary driver.

```
[  3702.470] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  3702.472] (--) PCI:*(0:3:0:0) 10de:1184:3842:3774 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfa000000/16777216, 0xd8000000/134217728, 0xd6000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000cc00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[  3702.472] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  3702.473] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/opengl/nvidia/extensions/libglx.so
[  3702.476] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  3702.476]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  3702.476]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  3702.476] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  355.11  Wed Aug 26 16:02:11 PDT 2015
[  3702.476] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  3702.476] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[  3702.476] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  3702.476]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  3702.476]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  3702.476] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  355.11  Wed Aug 26 15:38:55 PDT 2015
[  3702.476] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[  3702.476] (++) using VT number 7
```

Comment: Thank you. In my original post i uploaded the file. It does not contain any "Nvidia" and it does not contain "nouveau" either. Could you take a look and tell me which driver i am loading?

Comment: @Alex look for similar lines in your log.  Your logfile is very clearly identifying that it is loading the intel  drivers.

Comment: Looking at the log is not that helpful, as Xorg can load (and unload) multiple drivers while probing the hardware.

Answer (score 8):

One solution that I have found is to check what drivers are actually loaded while X is running.
On my system, the drivers are installed under

- `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/`
- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/`

so I can check what is currently loaded with

```
sudo lsof +D /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ +D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/
```

Right now I get

```
COMMAND  PID USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
Xorg    4473 root mem    REG  253,0    90360 536108 /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
```

so I guess I'm using the `modesetting` driver.

Comment: Or easier, not requiring to know where the drivers are installed, `sudo lsof | grep '_drv\.so$'`. I also get `evdev` from this (in addition to `nvidia`), but I think it's OK to get this extra info.

Comment: While this generally works as expected, in some Linux distros the output may list several drivers at once (with just a single instance of Xorg and a single GPU), like *ati_drv.so*, *amdgpu_drv.so*, *radeon_drv.so*.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an attempt to automatize the analysis of the log:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    logfile=/var/log/Xorg.0.log
else
    logfile="$1"
fi

sed -n 's@.* Loading .*/\(.*\)_drv.so@\1@p' "$logfile" |
    while read driver; do
        if ! grep -q "Unloading $driver" "$logfile"; then
            echo $driver
            break
        fi
    done
```

Any ideas how to make it simpler are welcome. Ideally I'd like to have a direct solution — by a query to Xorg instead of parsing its logs.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `glxinfo -B` from `mesa-utils` package,  and here is some sample pieces:

- using Nvidia driver 470.63.01 and RTX3070 card:

  ```
  OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070/PCIe/SSE2
  OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.63.01
  ```
- using intel integrated card and mesa driver:

  ```
  OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
  OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2)
  OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
  ```
- using pure CPU implemented opengl driver in a headless remote session:

  ```
  OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
  OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 128 bits)
  OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
  OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
  ```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, if - as you write - you are not sure, please reconsider testing and verifying your proposed solution before posting it as a (definitive) answer.